# Matlab's errorbar with matrix of colors

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

Is it possible to use the function `errorbar` with matrices (so it plots several plots with error bars) and give it a matrix of colors to use for the plots?

I haven't been able to make this work. Some attempts are:

```
x=1:10;
x=[x',x',x',x'];
y=rand(10,4);
e=0.1*rand(10,4);

% automatic colors work:
errorbar(x,y,e);

% custom ones don't (c is a 4 x 3 matrix of colors)
errorbar(x,y,e,c);
errorbar(x,y,e,c');
errorbar(x,y,e,'Color',c);
errorbar(x,y,e,'Color',c');
```

A solution is to use for-loops (and make a function that does this for repeting use) but I'm hoping there is something simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation of [Errorbar Series Properties](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbarseries-properties.html), the color property can only be a RGB triplet, a color string, or 'none'. So it seems impossible to obtain the desired behavior during the call to the `errorbar` function.

Anyway, you can fix this afterward without the use of a for loop or a function:

```
% Number of curves / colors
n = 4;

% Generate data and colors
x = repmat(1:10, [n 1])';
y = rand(10,n);
e = 0.1*rand(10,n);

c = jet(n);

% Plot
h = errorbar(x,y,e);

% Assign new colors
arrayfun(@(x,y) set(x, 'Color', y{:}), h, num2cell(c, 2)');
```

Comment: This is quite an smart way of solving it!